# replacing <img> to <ion-img> and images are very small

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I followed the guidance at [virtual scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/components/virtual-scroll/VirtualScroll/) and updated my list to be virtuallist.

all is fine but when i converted the [card background images](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-background) from `<img>` to `<ion-img>` the images appearing as background images to my cards are **very small**.  anything i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Image dimensions section](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/) in `ion-img` docs.

> By providing image dimensions up front, Ionic is able to accurately size up the image's location within the viewport, which helps lazy load only images which are viewable. Image dimensions can either by set as properties, inline styles, or external stylesheets. It doesn't matter which method of setting dimensions is used, but it's important that somehow each ion-img has been given an exact size.

You need to set the height and width for the image you want to show if you are using `ion-img` either through attributes or css styles.

Comment: thanks what if i want the image to consume the standard most width and height as it did prevously with `<img>` i tried `width="100%" height="100%"` but it didn't work.  i have a dynamic list of images and all i want is for them to take the current width and height automatically as was done before by `<img>` something like specifying `height="100%" width="100%"` sounds fine to me but it doesn't work any ideas?

Comment: you want it to have a specific dimension or vary according to each image? `ion-img` needs a certain size.. if you are able to retrieve image dimensions along with source.. you could set dynamically

Comment: i wanted it to vary according to each image.  understand from you now i have to do the calculation myself.  i find it strange, is this how people usually work with `ion-img`? they either have a fixed size or calculate it?

Comment: I suppose it is one of the tradeoffs with virtualscroll and optimization..you could just use `img` and try though..

Comment: @SurajRao how can I get the dimension dynamically? what if from firebase storage server? any idea how? [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53281894/9253041) is my problem